# TYPO3 - How to customize extension properly

Tags: typo3

I took one Project which is based on TYPO3 6.2.0

I needed to customize some extensions (templates) and I made this changes directly in the original template files.

I am just wondering what is standard and proper (update safe) way for customizing TYPO3 extensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typo3/2196/fluid-templating-in-typo3#t=2017012606054559697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the typoscript template of the extension (often setup.ts or setup.txt).

In newer extensions you will find something like

```
    plugin.tx_bla {
       view {
          templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:bla/Resources/Private/Templates/
          templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_bla.view.templateRootPath}
          partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:bla/Resources/Private/Partials/
          partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_bla.view.partialRootPath}
          layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:bla/Resources/Private/Layouts/
          layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_bla.view.layoutRootPath}
```

Then copy the templatefiles to your config extension or the fileadmin and adjust the path either in the constants (for the .1) or directly in the setup. After that clear system cache.

In older extension this might look likewise:

```
    plugin.tx_bla {
       view {
          templateRootPath = 
          partialRootPath =
          layoutRootPath =
```

Comment: In the first example you have only to copy the template files which you want to change.

Comment: And I forgot, you should enter the typoscript in your own typoscript template, which shoud load after the typoscript template of the extension. Best is never to edit the extension code.

Comment: @Jack70 you can edit your answer if you want to add something. And please don't advice people to put anything layout-related in the fileadmin. It works - nut it's bad practice.

Comment: @Jack70 thanks for the help. I tried to do this on my project but somehow typo3 use always default template.
Here is everything in detail --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874809/typo3-properly-edit-extension-template 

Thanks in advance!